# Automatically calculating a value from a Pandas dataframe column and assigning the value to a list for a Plotly Sankey Chart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

I am trying to automate the creation of a Sankey diagram in Plotly. I can generate it statically when I provide the values in a dataframe as shown below.

What I really want to do is automatically calculate these values on the fly with in the loop.
Excuse the really long post but I wanted to include as much information as possible.

**Environment**
Jupyter Notebook v6.4.8
Python v3.9.12 (64 bit)
Windows 11 (64 bit)

**Data**
The data I use for my testing is below. I save it in a file called stack.csv and read it into Pandas.The value column is there currently as I use it to define the thickness of lines in my Sankey chart

```
l1,l2,l3,value
A,D,J,1 
A,D,K,1 
A,E,L,1 
A,E,M,1 
B,F,N,1 
B,F,O,1 
B,G,P,1 
B,G,Q,1 
C,H,R,1 
C,H,S,1 
C,I,T,1 
C,I,U,1
```

I am trying to calculate a value for occurrences of an item in a pandas column l1, l2, l3 and assign the corresponding value to a list.

If I use .value_counts(), I can get the information I require for each column but I cant see how to assign it to my list.
l1 column

```
df1['l1'].value_counts()
A    4
B    4
C    4
Name: l1, dtype: int64
```

l2 column

```
df1['l2'].value_counts()
D    2
E    2
F    2
G    2
H    2
I    2
Name: l2, dtype: int64
```

l3 column

```
J    1
K    1
L    1
M    1
N    1
O    1
P    1
Q    1
R    1
S    1
T    1
U    1
Name: l3, dtype: int64
```

I am using the following loop to create the sankey values and it works fine when I specify value, I wish to drop value from the dataframe, and calculate the value via the loop.
Here is the list and loops in the function. which provides a valid chart.

```py
# Collect the data we need from a dataframe to populate our Sankey data - source, target, and value
def get_sankey_data(data,cols,values):
#def get_sankey_data(data,cols):
    # Empty lists to hold our data
    sankey_data = {
    'label':[],
    'source': [],
    'target' : [],
    'value' : []
    }
    # Set our counter to zero
    counter = 0

    # Start loop to retrieve data from our dataframe
    # While our counter is less than the length of our columns
    while (counter < len(cols) - 1):
        # For every unique entry in our columns 
        for parent in data[cols[counter]].unique():
            # Append the unique names to our label list
            sankey_data['label'].append(parent)
            for sub in data[data[cols[counter]] == parent][cols[counter+1]].unique():
                print(f'DEBUG1: sub is {sub}')
                sankey_data['source'].append(sankey_data['label'].index(parent))
                print(f"DEBUG2: Our Source Index {sankey_data['source']}")
                sankey_data['label'].append(sub)
                print(f"DEBUG3: Append sub label to our list {sankey_data['label']}")
                sankey_data['target'].append(sankey_data['label'].index(sub))
                print(f"DEBUG4: our Target index is {sankey_data['target']}")
                sankey_data['value'].append(data[data[cols[counter+1]] == sub][values].sum())
                print(f"DEBUG5: Our weight {sankey_data['value']}")
                #sankey_data['value'].append(data[data[cols].nunique()])
                #print(sankey_data['value'])
                
        counter +=1
    return sankey_data
```

[image]

if I change the line to

```
sankey_data['value'].append(data[data[cols[].value_counts())
```

I get 'KeyError: "None of [Index(['D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"'

The complete code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from webcolors import hex_to_rgb

data = pd.read_csv(r'stack.csv')   
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set our opacity
opacity = 0.4

# Our Colour Map
color_link = ['#FFFF00', '#1CE6FF', '#FF34FF', '#FF4A46', '#008941', '#006FA6', '#A30059', '#FFDBE5',
              '#7A4900', '#0000A6', '#63FFAC', '#B79762', '#004D43', '#8FB0FF', '#997D87', '#5A0007',
              '#809693', '#FEFFE6', '#1B4400', '#4FC601', '#3B5DFF', '#4A3B53', '#FF2F80', '#61615A',
              '#BA0900', '#6B7900', '#00C2A0', '#FFAA92', '#FF90C9', '#B903AA', '#D16100', '#DDEFFF',
              '#000035', '#7B4F4B', '#A1C299', '#300018', '#0AA6D8', '#013349', '#00846F', '#372101',
              '#FFB500', '#C2FFED', '#A079BF', '#CC0744', '#C0B9B2', '#C2FF99', '#001E09', '#00489C',
              '#6F0062', '#0CBD66', '#EEC3FF', '#456D75', '#B77B68', '#7A87A1', '#788D66', '#885578',
              '#FAD09F', '#FF8A9A', '#D157A0', '#BEC459', '#456648', '#0086ED', '#886F4C', '#34362D',
              '#B4A8BD', '#00A6AA', '#452C2C', '#636375', '#A3C8C9', '#FF913F', '#938A81', '#575329',
              '#00FECF', '#B05B6F', '#8CD0FF', '#3B9700', '#04F757', '#C8A1A1', '#1E6E00', '#7900D7',
              '#A77500', '#6367A9', '#A05837', '#6B002C', '#772600', '#D790FF', '#9B9700', '#549E79',
              '#FFF69F', '#201625', '#72418F', '#BC23FF', '#99ADC0', '#3A2465', '#922329', '#5B4534', 
              '#FDE8DC', '#404E55', '#0089A3', '#CB7E98', '#A4E804', '#324E72', '#6A3A4C'
             ]
# Collect the data we need from a dataframe to populate our Sankey data - source, target, and value
def get_sankey_data(data,cols):
    # Empty lists to hold our data
    sankey_data = {
    'label':[],
    'source': [],
    'target' : [],
    'value' : []
    }
    # Set our counter to zero
    counter = 0

    # Start loop to retrieve data from our dataframe
    # While our counter is less than the length of our columns
    while (counter < len(cols) - 1):
        # For every unique entry in our columns 
        for parent in data[cols[counter]].unique():
            # Append the unique names to our label list
            sankey_data['label'].append(parent)
            for sub in data[data[cols[counter]] == parent][cols[counter+1]].unique():
                sankey_data['source'].append(sankey_data['label'].index(parent))
                sankey_data['label'].append(sub)
                sankey_data['target'].append(sankey_data['label'].index(sub))
                sankey_data['value'].append(data[data[cols[counter+1]]].value_count())
                
        counter +=1
    return sankey_data

# We use this to create RGBA colours for our links. 
# This enables us to have semi opaque links which in turn
# allows us to see flows with out being obscured by solid colours
rgb_link_color = ['rgba({},{},{}, 0.4)'.format(
    hex_to_rgb(x)[0],
    hex_to_rgb(x)[1],
    hex_to_rgb(x)[2]) for x in color_link] 

# Call our get_sankey_data function - dataframe, colums, values   
sankey_chart4 = get_sankey_data(df1,['l1','l2','l3'])

# Style our initial Sankey chart
data = go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 75,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = sankey_chart4['label'],
      # I like all my nodes being the same colour
      # You could just use 'color_link' here or a seperate list of colors if you wanted
      color = "goldenrod"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = sankey_chart4['source'],
      target = sankey_chart4['target'],
      value = sankey_chart4['value'],
      color=rgb_link_color
    ))

# Prepare our chart
fig8 = go.Figure(data)

# Update chart with some customisations
fig8.update_layout(
    hovermode='x',
    title='Sankey Flows',
    font=dict(size=10, color='white'),
    paper_bgcolor='#51504f',
    margin={'t':50,'b':20}
)

# display chart
fig8.show()
```

If I look at the last set of debug info I print out I can see this from the original code with values for weight already calculated. IO tried value_count.values but that did not work either

```
DEBUG1: sub is U
DEBUG2: Our Source Index [0, 0, 3, 3, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8]
DEBUG3: Append sub label to our list ['A', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'F', 'G', 'C', 'H', 'I', 'D', 'J', 'K', 'E', 'L', 'M', 'F', 'N', 'O', 'G', 'P', 'Q', 'H', 'R', 'S', 'I', 'T', 'U']
DEBUG4: our Target index is [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26]
DEBUG5: Our weight [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This is my final sticking point on getting this Sankey fully automated so any help would be appreciated